# Is it possible to alias a branch in Git?

Tags: git, version-control, build-automation

I am looking into using Git on a massive scale.  I was hoping to increase adoption and make things easier by calling the `master` branch `trunk`.

This can and will give SVN users some feelings of comfort.  I know I can create a branch called `trunk`, but that seems to deviate from the Git norms and might cause some users to get confused.

I know that I can also create and delete tags to my heart's content but when I checkout those tags it tells me it is a non local branch which is just fine with me but probably not what I want to be doing.

I am a total Git newb but a seasoned professional at release and build systems.

**What I want to do is to be able to call master trunk.**  I have seen the ability to alias commands – does this apply for the names of versioned objects as well?

I know `git-svn` exists and other tools but the overhead of layered repository systems frightens me.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

You can rename the master branch trunk as Greg has suggested, or you can also create a trunk that is a symbolic reference to the master branch so that both git and svn users have the 'main' branch that they are used to.

```
git symbolic-ref refs/heads/trunk refs/heads/master
```

Note that trunk isn't a first class citizen. If you checkout `trunk` and perform a `git status` you will actually be on `master`, however you can use the `trunk` command in all places that you use the branch name (log, merge, etc.).

Comment: Serving both types of users is my main concern.  Is doing this on the server sufficient for the alias really to be completely visible?  I would vote you up by I don't have the cred for it yet.

Comment: Yes, it is. When users git fetch, they'll see a remote ref for both origin/master and origin/trunk. It won't necessarily be obvious from the fetch that they are the same thing, but when anyone pushes to either master or trunk then both branches will 'magically' be updated together.

Comment: I don't think symrefs transfer to clone if one use git:// or ssh protocol - you better check it.

Comment: I don't think they do, either, they just turn into normal remote refs, but they both still track the symref-ed central branch so in a way (perhaps) it doesn't matter. One difference I can think of is that you will have to fetch after pushing to notice that the other remote branch moved as well.

Comment: Be VERY careful about the order of the arguments. It's NOT the same as `ln -s` and if you put them the wrong way around, git will happily (and silently) clobber the HEAD ref for the real branch with a symbolic reference to something which does not exist (at which point you'd better hope that it's easy to recover the correct commit hash for that branch).

Comment: Also, don't try to remove a symbolic-ref with `git branch -d`. It's de-referenced even for that operation, and so you'll actually delete the source branch, leaving the reference behind (and it'll even let you do it if you currently have that branch checked out). You must use `git symbolic-ref --delete` (or if you're on an older version, you must manually delete the file).

Comment: Any idea how to do this in a Bitbucket repository? Can I push this symbolic refs somehow?

Comment: Is this only local or can it be done on the remote and keep the link between the alias and the target branch?

Comment: `git symbolic-ref refs/heads/master refs/heads/main` — if you're uncomfortable in a modern repository with your oldschool habits :)

Answer (score 11):

There is nothing special about the name "master" in Git, it's just called that by convention (and by default). You can certainly call it "trunk" if you like:

```
git branch -m master trunk
```

This is very much like Subversion, where the name "trunk" is only called that by convention too. You could have called the main branch "master" in Subversion.

Comment: Without knowing your new convention would new pullers not know where to start?

Comment: The HEAD of the common repository would point to "trunk", so pullers wouldn't have to know.

Answer (score 11):

This is a safety wrapper around the technique shown in Charles Bailey's answer.

```sh
$ git branch-alias <alias> <long-and-unwieldy-branch-name> # create alias
$ git branch-alias <alias> # create alias for current branch
$ git branch # view branches and branch aliases
$ git log <alias>
$ git checkout <alias>
$ git push origin <alias> # pushes the branch, not the alias/reference
$ git branch-alias -d <alias> # delete an alias safely
$ git branch-alias -h # help / usage details
```

Please note that a bug in git versions 2.7.0 - 2.8.2 (inclusive) caused "git branch" to display "alias -> alias" instead of "alias -> branch" for branch aliases.  I recommend upgrading to 2.8.3 or later if you are affected by that bug.

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# git branch-alias
# Author: Phil S.
# Version 1.13.1
version=1.13.1

# Creates branch aliases, so that you can refer to a long branch name
# by a convenient short alias.  This is particularly useful for branch
# names beginning with bug-tracker ID numbers (or similar), where the
# benefits of tab-completion are greatly reduced.

# This is mostly a "do what I mean" wrapper around "git symbolic-ref",
# with numerous safety measures included in order to eliminate the
# (otherwise considerable) risk of trashing a branch if you get your
# arguments wrong.

# Installation:
# Place this script somewhere in your PATH and name it "git-branch-alias"
# and you will be able to invoke it with "git branch-alias" as per the
# following examples.  If you have obtained the script from the git
# mailing list, please see the "Mailing list archives" note below.

# Examples:
# git branch-alias <alias> <long-and-unwieldy-branch-name> # create alias
# git branch-alias <alias> # create alias for current branch
# git branch # view branches and branch aliases
# git log <alias>
# git checkout <alias>
# git push origin <alias> # pushes the branch, not the alias/reference
# git branch-alias -d <alias> # delete an alias safely
# git branch-alias -h # help / usage details

# Caveats:
# Although everything else I've tried works seamlessly, I note that
# git merge <alias> will cause the alias name to be mentioned in the
# commit message, rather than the name of the real branch.  It would
# be nicer if the branch name appeared.

# Compatibility:
# Originally developed with git version 1.7.12.4
# Also tested with git versions 1.9.0, 2.5.4, 2.6.6, 2.8.3
#
# Related git changes between versions 1.7.12.4 and 2.8.3:
# git v1.8.0.1
#  * A symbolic ref refs/heads/SYM was not correctly removed with "git
#    branch -d SYM"; the command removed the ref pointed by SYM
#    instead.
#
# git v1.8.1
#  * "git symbolic-ref" learned the "-d $symref" option to delete the
#    named symbolic ref, which is more intuitive way to spell it than
#    "update-ref -d --no-deref $symref".
#
# git v2.6.5
#  * "git symbolic-ref" forgot to report a failure with its exit status.
#
#  I believe this is commit 3e4068ed90fd3c6f24303560113aae6dbb758699:
#  > symbolic-ref: propagate error code from create_symref()
#  > If create_symref() fails, git-symbolic-ref will still exit with
#  > code 0, and our caller has no idea that the command did nothing.
#  > This appears to have been broken since the beginning of time
#
#  As this affects symref creation only, the sole adverse effect here
#  would be an unintended message to the user if symref creation had
#  actually failed (but not even a misleading one, on account of our
#  reading the reference after its creation, and thus displaying an
#  error if it turned out to be invalid).
#
# git v2.8.3
#  * A change back in version 2.7 to "git branch" broke display of a
#    symbolic ref in a non-standard place in the refs/ hierarchy (we
#    expect symbolic refs to appear in refs/remotes/*/HEAD to point at
#    the primary branch the remote has, and as .git/HEAD to point at the
#    branch we locally checked out).
#
#  This caused "git branch" to display "ref -> ref" instead of "ref -> branch"
#  for branch aliases.  The functionality still works otherwise, but is not
#  nearly so convenient to work with when you cannot trivially see what each
#  alias points to.  This bug affected git versions 2.7.0 - 2.8.2 (inclusive).

# Change log:
# v1.13.1
# Change incorrect uses of git show-ref, introduced by v1.10 (including
# effective regression of v1.08), to use git symbolic-ref instead.
#
# v1.12:
# Fix the option handling for '--', and added it to the help text.
#
# v1.11:
# Minor tidy-ups.  Re-posted to git mailing list:
# https://www.mail-archive.com/git%40vger.kernel.org/msg161274.html
#
# v1.10:
# No longer dependent on refs existing as individual files, as they
# may be packed in .git/packed-refs.
#
# v1.09:
# POSIX-compatible option handling and output.
# Documented an issue with "git branch" in git versions 2.7.0 - 2.8.2.
#
# v1.08:
# Remove test git show-ref --verify --heads --quiet "refs/heads/${symref}"
# for asserting that the specified reference was valid before deleting a
# reference, as we need to permit the deletion of references to branches
# which have /already/ been deleted, and this test prevented that.
# n.b. We already had another validation test to fall back on, using
# git symbolic-ref "refs/heads/${symref}"
#
# v1.07:
# Minor tweaks.  Posted as feature-request to git mailing list:
# https://www.mail-archive.com/git%40vger.kernel.org/msg49171.html

# Mailing list archives:
# If you are reading this via the git mailing list archives at gmane.org
# then this code will probably be broken by an email obfuscation filter
# which automatically converts the symbol '@' to the string ' <at> '.
# Specifically the shell positional parameter expansion "$@" is changed
# to "$ <at> "), so don't try to use the version from gmane.  The copy
# of this message at http://www.mail-archive.com/git%40vger.kernel.org/
# should have the correct code.

command=$(basename $0)
if [ "${command##git-}" != "${command}" ]; then
    command="git ${command##git-}"
fi

# Print argument (and newline) to stdout or stderr.
stdout () {
    printf %s\\n "$1"
}
stderr () {
    printf %s\\n "$1" >&2
}

# Returns the supplied parameters suitably quoted for later evaluation.
quote () {
    for param; do
        printf %s "${param}Z" | sed "s/'/'\\\\''/g;1s/^/'/;\$s/Z\$/' /"
    done
}

# Process option parameters.
parameters=
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    case "$1" in
        ( -- ) {
            shift
            parameters="${parameters}$(quote "$@")"
            break
        };;
        ( -v | --version ) version_help=1; shift;;
        ( -h | --help    ) help=1; shift;;
        ( -d | --delete  ) delete=1; shift;;
        ( -* ) {
            stdout "Invalid option: $1"
            stdout
            shorthelp=1
            shift
        };;
        ( * ) { # non-option parameter
            parameters="${parameters}$(quote "$1")"
            shift
        };;
    esac
done

# Process non-option parameters.
eval "set -- ${parameters}"
symref=$1
branch=$2

# If too few or too many parameters were supplied, display shorthelp.
if [ -z "${symref}" ] || [ -n "$3" ]; then
    shorthelp=1
fi

# If displaying the version, exit immediately.
if [ -n "${version_help}" ]; then
    stdout "${command} version ${version}"
    exit 0
fi

# Don't let short help override long help.
if [ -n "${help}" ]; then
    shorthelp=
fi

# Include the usage summary in both short and long help.
if [ -n "${help}" ] || [ -n "${shorthelp}" ]; then
    cat <<EOF
Usage:
${command} [--] <alias> [<branch>]
${command} (-d | --delete) [--] <alias>
${command} (-v | --version)

EOF
fi

# n.b. Calling "git branch-alias --help" causes git to look for
# a man page for "git-branch-alias", so we shouldn't advertise
# the long option (although we support it if the script is called
# by its real name, rather than via git).
if [ -n "${shorthelp}" ]; then
    cat <<EOF
For help, use: ${command} -h

EOF
    exit 0
fi

# Detailed help.
if [ -n "${help}" ]; then
    cat <<EOF
Creates a symbolic reference <alias> referring to <branch>.
<branch> defaults to the current checked-out branch.

This symbolic reference acts as an alias for <branch>, and can be
used in its place.  More specifically, it WILL be dereferenced to
its target in nearly all situations, so for any given command you
should treat every usage of <alias> as if it were actually <branch>.

If either <alias> or <branch> begins with a hyphen, you can use the
'--' option to prevent subsequent arguments being treated as options.

To safely delete a branch alias, always use:
${command} -d <alias>

WARNING: These symbolic references appear in your branch list as:
 <alias> -> <branch>
and so you might be tempted to try to delete them like a branch:
 git branch -d <alias>

However this can cause problems.  In git versions prior to 1.8.0.1
<alias> will be dereferenced and you will instead delete the
branch it refers to (git will allow this even if you currently
have that branch checked out), and the symbolic reference will
still remain (referencing a branch which is no longer available).

In later versions of git the <alias> will be deleted rather than
the branch; however git will still not check to see whether you
currently have <alias> checked out, and will not prevent you
from deleting it in that situation.  This will leave your HEAD ref
in an invalid state.  Using ${command} -d <alias> resolves
this situation by first switching HEAD to <alias>'s target branch
if HEAD was currently set to <alias>.

EOF
    exit 0
fi

# Confirm the CWD is within a git repository.
#cwd=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
git=$(git rev-parse --git-dir)
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    exit 1
fi

# Use the current branch by default.
if [ -z "${branch}" ]; then
    branch=$(git symbolic-ref -q HEAD)
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        stderr "Could not establish current HEAD."
        exit 1
    fi
fi

# We expect plain branch names, but also accept the fully-qualified
# (refs/heads/NAME) paths needed by git symbolic-ref; so strip that
# refs/heads/ prefix if it is specified.
branch=${branch##refs/heads/}
symref=${symref##refs/heads/}

# Deleting a symref.
if [ -n "${delete}" ]; then
    # Verify that it IS a symbolic reference.
    if ! git symbolic-ref "refs/heads/${symref}" >/dev/null; then
        stderr "Error validating refs/heads/${symref} as symbolic reference."
        exit 1
    fi

    # If we currently have <symref> checked out, deleting it is bad
    # (as HEAD would no longer be a valid reference).  I believe we do
    # need to inspect the file here, as attempting to read the HEAD
    # reference via git dereferences it to its target branch, and thus
    # we are unable to distinguish between the branch and the symref.
    if grep "^ref: refs/heads/${symref}\$" "${git}/HEAD" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
        stdout "Cannot delete the currently checked out symbolic reference."
        branch=$(git symbolic-ref -q HEAD)
        if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
            stderr "Could not establish current HEAD."
            exit 1
        fi
        stdout "Switching HEAD to target branch ${branch}"
        # By using git symbolic-ref HEAD to find the target ref
        # and setting HEAD to that target, nothing really changes,
        # but we can now delete the reference safely.
        if ! git symbolic-ref HEAD "${branch}"; then
            stderr "Error updating HEAD from ${symref} to ${branch}"
            stderr "Aborting."
            exit 1
        fi
    fi

    # Delete the reference.
    # git 1.8.1+ provides: git symbolic-ref --delete <symref>
    # but older versions do not include that option, so we use
    # the backwards-compatible command.
    stdout "Deleting symbolic reference refs/heads/${symref}"
    git update-ref -d --no-deref "refs/heads/${symref}"
    exit $?
fi

# Creating a new symbolic reference.

# Error checking.  git symbolic-ref doesn't really do any, and will
# happily mess up your branches; particularly if you get the arguments
# the wrong way around (treating it like ln -s is a really bad idea).
if ! git show-ref --verify --heads --quiet "refs/heads/${branch}"; then
    stderr "Target branch refs/heads/${branch} does not exist."
    exit 1
fi
if target=$(git symbolic-ref -q "refs/heads/${symref}"); then
    stderr "Symbolic reference refs/heads/${symref} already exists:"
    stderr "  ${symref} -> ${target##refs/heads/}"
    stderr "To delete it, use: ${command} -d ${symref}"
    exit 1
elif git show-ref --verify --heads --quiet "refs/heads/${symref}"; then
    stderr "Reference refs/heads/${symref} already exists"
    stderr "(and is not a symbolic reference!)"
    exit 1
fi

# The parameters are good.
# Generate the reference and display the confirmed result.
if git symbolic-ref "refs/heads/${symref}" "refs/heads/${branch}"; then
    target=$(git symbolic-ref "refs/heads/${symref}")
    stdout "  ${symref} -> ${target##refs/heads/}"
else
    stderr "Failed to create branch alias."
    exit 1
fi
# EOF
```

Upstream feature request:
https://www.mail-archive.com/git@vger.kernel.org/msg161274.html

Comment: This fails for me with Git 2.7.0 on OS X in zsh: `Target refs/heads/-l does not exist.` no matter what arguments I use.

Comment: Thanks for the responses!  In answer to your question, *yes*, this was the exact message: `Target refs/heads/-l does not exist.`  

I tested under bash, and it still did it.  I reversed the arguments, and it still did it.  I did `unalias git` in zsh, to ensure nothing was interfering, and it still did it.  I used the complete path to git, and it still did it.  I used the full path to `git-branch-alias` and it still did it.

Comment: I don't think this could be related, but `which -a git` shows 2 versions on my system.  I don't think the second could be in use at all, but ... I've got `/usr/local/bin/git` and `/usr/bin/git`, with the first one earlier in the PATH.  The second on is 2.5.4.

Comment: Ah, I see the problem now. I searched the script for `-l` and found an instance in the `getopt` call to define the command line options, and I've realised that I'm using the GNU `getopt` syntax, which isn't POSIX compatible, and in particular is not supported by OSX by default. That might be enough info for you to figure out the appropriate changes. If not, I'll try to make a more portable version of that script in the near future.

Comment: I finally got around to this. Could you test the new version 1.09-rc1 I've added to the answer? If all is well, I'll post an update to the git mailing list as well.

Comment: Please note that in git versions 2.7.0 to 2.8.0 (inclusive) `git branch` displays symrefs incorrectly as `ref -> ref` instead of `ref -> branch`. Versions 2.6.6 and earlier show the correct output, and I believe the regression will be fixed in the next 2.8.x release. For the affected versions you can use `git symbolic-ref` to check the target for a given reference. You could also use `git branch-alias REF` (which usually *creates* the symref) to inspect an already-existing REF, as when it already exists the script will tell you what it points to (as it bails out).

Comment: @iconoclast: Please could you let me know if this version works? (or *anyone* reading this who uses OSX? I don't have anyone else to test it...)

Comment: I just upgraded, and I'm now at 2.8.2, so if I understand you correctly I'll need to wait until 2.8.3 before I can test this in any meaningful way.

Comment: @iconoclast: 2.8.3 has now been released. The 6th item in the release notes covers the bug discussed in the previous comments: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.8.3.txt

Comment: awesome—I look forward to using it.

Comment: Did this upstream feature request ever get anywhere? With a lot of git repositories moving from `master` to `main` these days, a tool like this would be very useful to keep local clones consistent so you don't have to remember which repos have and haven't switched.

Comment: @asmeurer, I've implemented this - `git branch --alias master` works if you're on `main`, and `git branch --alias master main` if you're not. I submitted a patch to the mailing list in 2019, but never went anywhere. http://public-inbox.org/git/47CA9077-E8C1-4093-8B36-2D5D3DE2D886@gmail.com/.  It's all on github if anyone wants to play with it https://github.com/git/git/compare/v2.26.0...iCodeSometime:master

Answer (score 0):

Tes, using `git symbolic-ref <alias-branch> <targetbranch>`:

```
git symbolic-ref refs/heads/trunk refs/heads/master
git symbolic-ref refs/heads/master refs/heads/main
```

Hut the "current branch" (`git branch --show-current`) would be "incorrect" (would still show the target branch instead of your alias branch):

Before Git 2.39 (Q4 2022), after checking out a "branch" that is a symbolic-ref that points at another branch, "[`git symbolic-ref HEAD`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4a48c7d25f941532befaf3320f95f16d3c62b530/Documentation/git-symbolic-ref.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-symbolic-ref))</sup> reports the underlying branch, not the symbolic-ref the user gave checkout as argument.

> 

**The command learned the "`--no-recurse`" option to stop after dereferencing a `symbolic-ref` only once.**

See [commit b77e3bd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b77e3bdd978bda6415e819972f962b3b16d22a71) (07 Oct 2022) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4a48c7d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4a48c7d25f941532befaf3320f95f16d3c62b530), 21 Oct 2022)</sup>

> ### [`symbolic-ref`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b77e3bdd978bda6415e819972f962b3b16d22a71): teach "--[no-]recurse" option

> Suppose you are managing many maintenance tracks in your project, and some of the more recent ones are `maint-2.36` and `maint-2.37`.
> Further imagine that your project recently tagged the official 2.38 release, which means you would need to start `maint-2.38` track soon, by doing:
>
> ```
> $ git checkout -b maint-2.38 v2.38.0^0
> $ git branch --list 'maint-2.3[6-9]'
> * maint-2.38 
>   maint-2.36 
>   maint-2.37
> ```
>
> So far, so good.
> But it also is reasonable to want not to have to worry about which maintenance track is the latest, by pointing a more generic-sounding 'maint' branch at it, by doing:
>
> ```
> $ git symbolic-ref refs/heads/maint refs/heads/maint-2.38
> ```
>
> which would allow you to say "whichever it is, check out the latest maintenance track", by doing:
>
> ```
> $ git checkout maint
> $ git branch --show-current
> maint-2.38
> ```
>
> It is arguably better to say that we are on 'maint-2.38' rather than on 'maint', and git merge/pull would record into maint-2.38 and not into maint, so I think what we have is a good behaviour.
>
> One thing that is slightly irritating, however, is that I do not think there is a good way (other than "cat .git/HEAD") to learn that you checked out 'maint' to get into that state.
> Just like the output of "[`git branch --show-current`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b77e3bdd978bda6415e819972f962b3b16d22a71/Documentation/git-branch.txt#L179)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt---show-current))</sup> shows above, "[`git symbolic-ref`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b77e3bdd978bda6415e819972f962b3b16d22a71/Documentation/git-symbolic-ref.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-symbolic-ref))</sup> HEAD would report 'refs/heads/maint-2.38', bypassing the intermediate symbolic ref at 'refs/heads/maint' that is pointed at by HEAD.
>
> The internal `resolve_ref()` API already has the necessary support for stopping after resolving a single level of a symbolic-ref, and we can expose it by adding a "--[no-]recurse" option to the command.

`git symbolic-ref` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b77e3bdd978bda6415e819972f962b3b16d22a71/Documentation/git-symbolic-ref.txt#L49-L57):

> ```
>  'git symbolic-ref' [-q] [--short] [--no-recurse] <name>
> ```
>
> ### `--recurse`
>
> ### `--no-recurse`
>
> When showing the value of  as a symbolic ref, if
>  refers to another symbolic ref, follow such a chain
> of symbolic refs until the result no longer points at a
> symbolic ref (`--recurse`, which is the default).
> `--no-recurse` stops after dereferencing only a single level
> of symbolic ref.