# Is it possible to have 2 names for a single git branch?

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to alias a branch in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549920/is-it-possible-to-alias-a-branch-in-git)

We have a public and an internal version for our code. Right now we have 2 branches and we have to manually commit change to each to keep them in sync. Is there a way to create an alias or something that will let devs with in a single branch with 2 different names?

The idea is one group of devs only knows and works with public version so they would do a `git checkout pub-1.0.0` and another department worth of devs only knows internal versions so they would do a `git checkout dev-1.2.3`.

Both groups devs should be working with the same code. a commit to pub-1.0.0 should be seen in dev-1.2.3 and visa verse.

Is this setup possible?

Comment: I believe this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549920/is-it-possible-to-alias-a-branch-in-git

Comment: See also [Git 2.39 (Q4 2022) git symbolic-ref --no--recurse HEAD`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74172104/6309) to find the name of your alias branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Is it possible to alias a branch in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549920/is-it-possible-to-alias-a-branch-in-git) :

> you can create a symbolic reference to the master branch:
>
> ```
> git symbolic-ref refs/heads/trunk refs/heads/master
> ```
>
> Note that trunk isn't a first class citizen. If you checkout trunk and
>   perform a git status you will actually be on master, however you can
>   use the trunk command in all places that you use the branch name (log,
>   merge, etc.).

Comment: Is this still valid when *not* dealing with the master? I would need to create a reference to an existing branch, not to master.

Comment: You can use any branch name, as long as it exists.