# How to create a GIT branch that point to another branch instead of a commit

Tags: git, git-branch

Knowing that a branch is a pointer to the last commit. By example, the master branch is linked to the commit C1.

I want to know if it's possible to link a branch to another branch instead of a commit, which would make it a pointer of pointer (for those accustomed in C).

By example, I would like the master branch point to a release branch (by example 1.1). And if by any chance, a commit would happen in the branch 1.1, the master HEAD would follow the 1.1 HEAD.

Comment: Are you trying to solve the organizational issue with technical tools? What is the *real* task behind this "solution"?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. It defeats the purpose of having branches in the first place. If you want to keep a branch up to date with another simply fetch and merge.

Perhaps you can add a git hook that will run every time you commit on a branch and the git hook can do a pull for you from that other branch that you want to keep up to date with.

Comment: Any reference can be symbolic.  The `HEAD` reference is usually symbolic, but you can create a symbolic ref in the branch name-space by using a name that starts with `refs/heads/`, e.g., `git symbolic-ref refs/heads/INDIR refs/heads/master`.  I have to ask the same question as @zerkms though.

Comment: @torek I didn't see this before answering, why not make it an answer?

Comment: @jthill: it's not really a true branch.  It works for some (many?) purposes but not all.  So I'm not sure it's a *good* answer. :-)

Comment: @(all here) - if you're publishing a stable/testing/experimental branches, and there aren't any even alpha-quality experiments going on, just set experimental to track testing until it's time.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can make branch aliases or aliases to any ref.  Say:

```
git symbolic-ref refs/heads/trackmaster refs/heads/realmaster
```

and you no longer have to manually catch up (possibly temporarily-)joined LOD's

Answer (score 3):

My apologies if this post ought rather to be a comment instead of an answer.

<s>Git does not support aliases for branches.</s>

Some good discussion on this subject in the answers to this StackOverflow question:

[git - branch alias?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365946/git-branch-alias)

CORRECTION:

Actually, it looks like symbolic-ref is the way to alias a branch.  There's a feature request on the Git mailing list with more info.

http://www.mail-archive.com/git%40vger.kernel.org/msg49171.html