# Git - give one branch two names?

Tags: git, github-enterprise

Is it possible to give one branch two names?

The situation I have is that our team gave a branch a long, unwieldy name. Now, I'd like to give it another, shorter name for convenience. Is that possible? We're using github enterprise.

Edit: I need the alias (by whatever mechanism it is aliased) to exist in the central github enterprise-hosted repo, and NOT just be local to my repo.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/549920/is-it-possible-to-alias-a-branch-in-git

Comment: @PSkocik That's not the same thing at all. Based on the accepted answer, that question is looking for a local solution. I need one that will exist in the hosted repo.

Comment: This is , because you dont want to remove the old name for the branch ? (so, you need to preserve the branch with both names ?)

Comment: @dseminara Yep, I don't want anything to break because of absence of the original branch name.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to have a local branch with whatever name you'd like (shorter, more convenient) track a remote branch with the original name:

```
git branch --track short-name long-unwieldly-branch-name-from-remote
```

Comment: To do the same and checkout the branch immediately `git checkout -b short-name origin/long-unwieldly-branch-name-from-remote`

Answer (score -1):

I think that a symbolic reference is what you're looking for:

[Is it possible to alias a branch in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549920/is-it-possible-to-alias-a-branch-in-git/549949#549949)

Comment: No, sadly this can't be pushed to the hosted github repo.