# Make git master follow / track another local branch

Tags: git

We have a Git repository with a couple of branches that live side by side, e.g. `branch1`, `branch2` and `branch3`. The goal is to make `master` always point to the same commit as the HEAD of, say, `branch3`.

When googling the term "branch tracking" the articles almost always concern *remote* tracking. Can the same be achieved for local branches?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try and use [`git symbolic-ref`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-symbolic-ref):

```
git symbolic-ref refs/heads/master refs/heads/branch3
```

Comment: I'm surprised. I don't understand which `git symbolic-ref` syntax of the three detailed in the man page you're using here. Does `refs/heads/master` count as a symbolic reference?

Comment: @Jubobs it simply modifies the content to `.git/refs/heads/master` file, in order to reference not a SHA1, but the name of another branch. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/549949/6309