# Creating aliases for Git branch names

Tags: git, branch, alias, git-checkout

Suppose I have the following branches in git:

- `master`
- `release-2014-11-02-some-long-text`

I would like to easily switch between those to, like this:

```
git checkout devel # checkout to master
git checkout release # checkout to the branch release currently points/aliases to, in this case:  release-2014-11-02-some-long-text (I would like to change this alias from time to time)
```

How can I do that in Git?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can try using [`git symbolic-ref`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-symbolic-ref) (as mentioned in "[Is it possible to alias a branch in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/549949/6309)"):

```
git symbolic-ref refs/heads/devel   refs/heads/master
git symbolic-ref refs/heads/release refs/heads/release-2014-11-02-some-long-text
```

You can find a [similar example in this gist](https://gist.github.com/rkhmelyuk/11239443).