# How to switch from detached head to attached head in GIT

Tags: git, shell

Sometimes when debugging I'll checkout commits from a branch. This puts me in detached head. Often I can use `git checkout -` to go back to the branch head. But sometimes I'll checkout multiple commits in a row so this will just bring me back to the last commit. Is there a more surefire way to get back to the head of the branch? Is there a way without typing the whole branch name e.g. `git checkout <branch-name>`?

Comment: If your issue is with typing long names, consider using a shell that has completion options, and setting up Git completion that will complete branch names for you. (I've used this and actively hate it because it will complete *branch* names when I'm expecting *file* names, but everyone has different tastes.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the other answer but I came up with another solution

```
git checkout `git branch --sort=committerdate | tail -1`
```

`git branch --sort=comitterdate` will return branches in the order in which they were last checked out.

Heres what the output will look like when you are on a detached head, it doesnt keep track of history of detached branches so the first result will be the last non detached branch you were at.

```
  branch1
  branch2
  master
* (HEAD detached at 1d4de8881)
  last-non-detached-head-branch-checked-out
```

Answer (score 1):

The sure-fire way to get back to the head of a branch is

```
git checkout <branch-name>  # such as master
```

You may have to deal with any uncommitted changes first, and if you've made any commits in the detached state you will be warned that you're leaving them behind. You can `cherry-pick` them into the branch, if they are valuable.

To create an alias for a branch name, you can use a variable in whatever shell you're using:

```
short="very-long-annoying-branch-name"
git co $short
```

git symbolic refs don't appear useful for this purpose. Another idea is to create git aliases for checking out specific branches.

Actual transcript:

```
$ git config --global alias.coms 'checkout master'
$ git coms
Already on 'master'
Your branch is ahead of 'remotes/origin/master' by 7 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

Maybe avoid `--global` for branch names very specific to particular repos.

Comment: got it, I was hoping for a way where I dont have to type the whole branch name in

Comment: Maybe git aliases can help here; you can make a `git gohome` or something. Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26944235/creating-aliases-for-git-branch-names

Comment: Unfortunately, no. If you check out using a symbolic-ref, you will get to the right commit, but you will be in a detached state.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to [@Kaz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65583974/9164010), you may want to give a try to [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog)?

Then, `git checkout HEAD@{1}` for example.

For more details, you can run `man gitrevisions` or fetch the accompanying online [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions#Documentation/gitrevisions.txt-emltrefnamegtltngtemegemmaster1em). Excerpt:

> […]
> **`<refname>@{<n>}, e.g. master@{1}`**
>
> A ref followed by the suffix `@` with an ordinal specification enclosed in a brace pair (e.g. `{1}`, `{15}`) specifies the n-th prior value of that ref. For example `master@{1}` is the immediate prior value of master while `master@{5}` is the 5th prior value of master. This suffix may only be used immediately following a ref name and the ref must have an existing log (`$GIT_DIR/logs/<refname>`).
> […]