# Why i can't push my project to my Repository on Github

Tags: git, github

i just follow this steps to upload this project to repository in my github

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DOIon.png)

and this problem comes, how i can fix this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3Nkt.png)

Comment: What specifically is the error?

Comment: MSI Gaming@MSI MINGW64 ~/Documents/Project/SistemAkademik ((c273eb3...))
$ git commit -m "Add all my files"
HEAD detached from 9b3e8f9
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)  
        modified:   sia (modified content, untracked content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")

It's like that

Comment: @Furnox21 Welcome to SO! Please avoid posting links to images.  Among other concerns (dead links) it excludes those with visual impairments from contributing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to switch from detached head to attached head in GIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65583909/how-to-switch-from-detached-head-to-attached-head-in-git)

Comment: You're using submodules, which is probably how you got this detached-HEAD state. But if you're a beginner in Git, you should *avoid* submodules: don't tackle them until you understand Git fairly well. (They cause even somewhat experienced Git users a lot of pain, hence their nickname of *sob*-modules.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stage your modified files first with commands :

```
git add <yourfile>
```

Git itself have stage area which was contains of your file that going to commited to your repo.
For better explanation why it need to be [staged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878358/why-would-i-want-stage-before-committing-in-git)...

well If you don't want to git adding them one by one xD, you can use

```
git add -u // will added your modified files to stage 
git add * // which will add all of your files including your new files (literally everything to stage)
git commit -a // will commiting
```

A little bonus, [Git Cheat Sheet xD](https://education.github.com/git-cheat-sheet-education.pdf)
Also i have little advie, it was better if you work with your code around with Visual Code... its more simply to commit a changes to your repo in github with feature there.