# Define variables in a git config file?

Tags: git, alias, git-config

I have a set of git aliases that I use both in my personal life and also at my professional positions. Because of long-standing convention in git usage, I've hardcoded `master` as a default "main" branch in many of these aliases.

However, I happen to be working at an institution where the convention is to use `main` as the main branch. This means a lot of my aliases break when I try to use them, because I've hard-coded an assumption of a branch called `master`, and and ensuant usage thereof.

Instead of changing the instances of `master` in my aliases file, and maintaining separate versions of that alias file for different situations, I wonder if I can instead use a variable in my alias definitions, one that I could set in my `.gitconfig`. Something like:

```
$ cat .gitconfig

...
[variables]
  DEFAULT_BRANCH = main

[include]
  path = myaliases.git

$ cat myaliases.git

bclean = "!f() { git branch --merged ${1-DEFAULT_BRANCH} | grep -v " ${1-DEFAULT_BRANCH}$" | xargs -r git branch -d; }; f"
```

Instead of

```
bclean = "!f() { git branch --merged ${1-master} | grep -v " ${1-master}$" | xargs -r git branch -d; }; f"
```

Comment: Would [aliasing the branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/549949/11659881) work?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this directly with a Git alias (as in the parts that Git expands).  You *can* do it with a *shell* alias (as in parts that the shell expands, either through a direct shell alias, or through a Git alias that invokes the shell with `!`).

[The comment from Kraigolas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68156169/define-variables-in-a-git-config-file#comment120459233_68156169) that suggests using a symbolic name is also a good proposition for some cases: just make `master` a symbolic name for `main` in these repositories.  The only *normal* symbolic name is `HEAD`, though, and symbolic names have certain weirdnesses about them: for instance, it used to be the case that an attempt to delete a symbolic name, deleted instead its target.

Much more directly, you can use `[include]` directives.  For any repository where you want your aliases to use `main`, simply include a (sub-)version of your alias file that replaces `master` with `main`.  Of course that's what you said you don't want to do—but how often do you edit these aliases?  You can write a little script that generates the alternate file from your "main" config file (or should I call it your "master" file?), and run that whenever you make an edit.  Note that you need only override the aliases with later aliases via inclusion:

```
[include]
    path = ~/.gitconfig.main
```

As for a script that massages the aliases in `~/.gitconfig`, there would be several ways to tackle this.  My preference would be to move the master-related aliases and have `~/.gitconfig` include `~/.gitconfig.master` itself so that the script is just:

```
sed -e s/master/main/ < ~/.gitconfig.master > ~/.gitconfig.main
```

However, you could get fancy and write something that runs `git config --global --list`, extracts the `alias.*` entries, and so on.  This gets difficult because you then have to deal with quoting.

Here's a silly example:

```
$ grep silly ~/.gitconfig
        silly = rev-parse master
$ cat ~/.gitconfig.main
[alias]
        silly = rev-parse main
```

Running `git silly` in a repository without the `include` section runs `git rev-parse master`.  Running `git silly` in a repository *with* the `include` section runs `git rev-parse main`.

Comment: Could you add some fleshed-out example code or commands to your answer?

Comment: "how often do you edit these aliases? " Not often, but really the issue is I don't want to juggle alias files between work, which uses `main`, and elsewhere, where `master` is common

Comment: There's no need to *juggle files*. You just add `[include] path = ~/.gitconfig.main` at the end of your `.git/config` in a repository where you want the `main`-ized aliases.

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest two possible solutions:

##### 1. Use .zshrc

You can define a variable in your .zshrc file (or .bashrc depending on what shell you use)

```
# ~/.zshrc
export GIT_DEFAULT_BRANCH="main"
```

then in your git config file

```
# ~/.gitconfig
[alias]
        default = "!git checkout $GIT_DEFAULT_BRANCH"
```

You have to use `!` syntax to make this work and any time you make a change to the variable in .zshrc you will need to reload the .zshrc file with:

```
$ . $HOME/.zshrc
```

##### 2. Determine the default branch using refs/remotes/origin/HEAD

This requires a bit more complexity but it has worked well for me. Basically there is a git command `git symbolic-ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD` which will tell you the default branch associated with your origin remote (the central server that you git push to e.g. github, gitlab, bitbucket). When I run this command on my current work laptop I see the following:

```
$ git symbolic-ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
refs/remotes/origin/main
```

All we want here is the last part of the path `main`. I've been using ruby and a [pipe operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834086/what-is-a-simple-explanation-for-how-pipes-work-in-bash) to get it with the command

```
$ git symbolic-ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD | ruby -e 'puts gets.split(%q[/]).pop'
main
```

So the above alias that checks out the default branch could be written as:

```
# ~/.gitconfig
[alias]
        default = "!git checkout `git symbolic-ref refs/remotes/origin/HEAD | ruby -e 'puts gets.split(%q[/]).pop'`"
```

*caveat: I've only tried this in a zsh shell so I don't know if it would work in other shells.*

The downside is that this is much more complex and cumbersome when you want access to this value in multiple aliases. The upside is that you don't need to change any variables as this alias will simply work in any git repository with an origin remote so long as you have ruby installed in your environment.