# Is there a way to disallow creating a git branch with a particular name, locally?

Tags: git

I have some projects which use "master" and others which use "main" and I am constantly accidentally checking out one or the other. The big problem is when on a project that uses "main" and also heroku, which uses "master", so `git checkout master` succeeds and seems normal.

Is there a way to configure something locally so that creating this branch will blow up?

Comment: How would this help you if you have a project which uses both `main` and `master` already, and your problem is that you are accidentally checking out the wrong one? (If that's not what your problem is I didn't understand your scenario)

Comment: Also what's the big deal? No law requires _you_ to have a local `master` ever, no matter what the remote has.

Comment: Although I don't understand exactly what your problem is, have you looked into git hooks?

Comment: You could make a symlink (or symbolic ref) one to the other within your `.git/refs/heads` directory. Then regardless of which name you use, it will always refer to the same branch effectively.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/549920/is-it-possible-to-alias-a-branch-in-git for what @JeffMercado suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I came up with in .git/hooks/post-checkout

```
if [ `git branch --show-current` == "master" ]; then
  echo "DO NOT USE MASTER"
  git checkout main
  git branch -d master
fi
```

Comment: branch names are purely repo-local, you can also `git checkout -tb master origin/main; git symbolic-ref refs/heads/{master,main}` and now your master and main branches are the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way integrated to git to do that.

You may write `post-checkout` hook, that would either prevent switch automatically to the other branch, or write a warning big enough on your screen when it detects you are on the "bad" branch ; plus a `pre-push` hook that would prevent to push the "bad" branch to the remote.

---

Two quick and dirty hacks :

- create an empty file under `.git/refs/heads`, and make that file read only :

```
# under linux :
touch .git/refs/heads/main
chmod a-rwx .git/refs/heads/main
```

The file seems to stay there even when `git pack-refs` runs, but I haven't checked if it would be kept in all scenarios.

- create a branch `main/dontcreate` in your local repository

In its current implementation, `git` doesn't allow to have both a branch named `main` *and* branches named `main/something` -- `git` still wants to be able to create files under `.git/refs/heads` to represent branches, and this would create both a file and a directory with the same name.

---

Note that both these hacks rely on the current implementation of `git` (git v2.33 at the moment), which could change in a future version.

Comment: the `post-checkout` and `pre-push` hooks are exactly what i'm looking for - how do i do that?